# How to check if marker is out of specific constant bounds? - Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm new in GoogleMaps API v3, I have speficied a bounds in my geocoder config, with this code:

```
bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                     new google.maps.LatLng(-27.242171228168928, -27.242171228168928), 
                     new google.maps.LatLng(-26.99771082240342, -109.0823670364868))
```

Now, the search are more accurately :-) But, now I want to display an alert if user drags the marker out of THAT bounds specified. How I can achieve that?

In short, I want to prevent the user place the marker outside the region

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to have an event listener for when the marker is dragged, using the bounds' `contains` function.  Also if you really want to prevent them dragging that marker outside of the bounds, you probably also need to keep track of what the position was originally, and reset it back there if you have to.  Something like this:

```js
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                     new google.maps.LatLng(-27.242171228168928, -27.242171228168928), 
                     new google.maps.LatLng(-26.99771082240342, -109.0823670364868));

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5087531, -0.1281153),
    draggable: true
});

var markerPosition;

marker.addListener('dragstart', function() {
    markerPosition = this.getPosition();
});

marker.addListener('dragend', function() {
    if (bounds.contains(this.getPosition()) == false) {
        alert("You've dragged the marker outside of the bounds allowed. We've reset it");

        this.setPosition(markerPosition);
    }
});
```

PS: I've also extended this answer into [a blog post](https://duncan99.wordpress.com/2015/03/21/google-maps-api-locked-draggable-markers/), including how to do the same with a polygon as well as bounds.

Answer (score 1):

On a LatLngBounds object you can call the contains() function which takes a LatLng parameter and returns true\false  if its contained with the LatLngBounds you have defined.

So in your case you can listen to the dragend event on your marker and in the listener handler use the approach above.